# How do you setup crosswalk on android to load files from the local external storage?

Tags: android, android-webview, crosswalk

I am developing an app on Android using Crosswalk that show files that I need to download from a web service. I would rather download the files to the external storage. But when I try to load them into the Crosswalk WebView I get a "Not allowed to load local resource:" error. I tried opening them directly and through a json manifest with csp properties like this (and some variations):

```
"csp" : "default-src 'self' file:// http:// https://"
```

My current setting are rather permissive:

```
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   mXWalkView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But still no success. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

**UPDATE**

To clarify and so that it doesn't get lost in the comments:
I am using the following code to load the file:

```
String url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/wh_files/index.html";
mXWalkView.load(url, null);
```

Comment: `load files from the local external storage?` AND `would rather download the files to the external storage` ??? Now is it FROM or TO?

Comment: The apps downloads the asset files (js, css, images, etc.) from a web service into the external storage and the I would like that the webview opens them and shows them from there.

Comment: There is no code where a file is loaded or one of these files is used.

Comment: I use mXWalkView.load(url, null) to load the file directly or mXWalkView.loadAppFromManifest(url, null) to load the file from the manifest. The call is successful the problem as I said is the "Not allowed to load local resource:" error.

Comment: You should of course tell us the value of url.getPath() and url.toString() and post a part of the html source that tries to load those files. How can we ever know what you are doing?

Comment: The url is : file:///storage/emulated/0/wh_files/index.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was finally able to track down the problem and it didn't have anything to do with the implementation. There seems to be a hardware problem on the device and the file that I wanted to load was corrupted.

I guess that the important lesson to learn is that the  **"Not allowed to load local resource:" error** not always means what it says.